# Which place does "west side" in Hamilton Leithauser + Rostam's "A 1000 Times" refer to?

Tags: lyrics

This is the line from the [lyrics](https://genius.com/Hamilton-leithauser-rostam-a-1000-times-lyrics) "I left my room, on the west side".

Does this refer to the upper west side in nyc? Does this even refer to a specific place at all?

The [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9FILAkKinQ) seems to show some part of nyc (I could be wrong about that though).

EDIT: Thanks to [the answer in this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123195/where-is-this-location-from-the-a-1000-times-music-video/123197#123197), I now know that the location of the music video is on 1st Avenue and 74th Street, Upper East Side - which makes the "on the west side" part of the lyrics a little more confusing to me.